# IE8 Paperclip upload not saving form nor upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer-8

I have tried uploading a photo to one of my forms on Internet Explorer 8. Having tested the form, I found the form will submit without trying to upload an image. I researched the internet and having been able to find a clear answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added `:multipart => true` to your form helper?

`<%= form_for @your_model, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i had to add this Jquery code to make it work:

```
$( "form#upload-form" )
  .attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" )
  .attr( "encoding", "multipart/form-data" )
  ;
```

It was the only thing that let internet explorer actually upload my photos.